# Erro “Call to a member function query() on a non-object in"

Tags: php, sql

Alguma ideia do que esta havendo de errado?
O que devo fazer para fazer funcionar corretamente?
Agradeço desde já a atenção !!

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\Users....\xampp\htdocs\install.php on line 4

```
    <?PHP
//######################## SHOW TICKERS AND NEWS #######################
$time = time();
    $query = $SQL->query("SELECT * FROM `players` ORDER BY `experience` DESC")->fetch();
    $query2 = $SQL->query('SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `players` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;')->fetch();
    $housesfree = $SQL->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `houses` WHERE `owner`=0;')->fetch();
    $housesrented = $SQL->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `houses` WHERE `owner`=1;')->fetch();
    $players = $SQL->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `players` WHERE `id`>0;')->fetch();
    $accounts = $SQL->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `accounts` WHERE `id`>0;')->fetch();
    //$banned = $SQL->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `bans` WHERE `id`>0;')->fetch();
    $guilds = $SQL->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `guilds` WHERE `id`>0;')->fetch();
    ///End Queries ///
```

Comment: coloca o trecho onde você faz a conexão com o banco de dados, pois esse $SQL não é um objeto de Banco de Dados Definido, existe um erro antes na conexão.

Comment: O arquivo não possui o trecho de conexão. Na verdade acredito que ele esteja em outro arquivo .php. Sou completamente inexperiente em .php. Segue o link com o trecho de conexão: https://pastebin.com/GKcq3SBR

Comment: Onde a variável `$SQL` é definida?